# Why are Leaflet's Map Methods Missing?

Tags: leaflet

I have created a Leaflet map by calling `var map = L.map('leaflet', options);` but that just makes an object full of underscore-prefixed private values:

```
Object.keys(map) === ["options", "_container", "_leaflet_id", "_containerId", `"_fadeAnimated", "_panes", "_paneRenderers", "_mapPane", "_controlCorners", "_controlContainer", "_onResize", "_targets", "_events", "_zoom", "_loaded", "_lastCenter", "_size", "_sizeChanged", "_pixelOrigin", "_firingCount", "_handlers", "_layers", "_zoomBoundLayers", "_initHooksCalled", "dragging", "doubleClickZoom", "scrollWheelZoom", "touchZoom", "boxZoom", "keyboard", "_zoomAnimated", "_proxy", "_layersMaxZoom", "_layersMinZoom"]`
```

The map still shows up.  There is no console error.  But I can't call things like `map.getCenter()` or `map.getContainer()` because those methods do not exist on `map`.  Why are those methods not on the `map`?

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem on a jsfiddle or plnkr ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns only enumerable *own* properties of an object.

By definition, methods are supposed to be inherited from a class, and not be *own* properties.

In JavaScript (ES5), there is no formal "class", so it translates to "methods be inherited from the *prototype*". But still not *own* properties.

Leaflet does a good job in that it respects this practice.

For instance, instead of analyzing `Object.keys(map)`, directly look into `map` (in modern browsers like Firefox, doing `console.log(map)` will give you the ability to expand the object) and search for `__proto__` (could be the last item): this is the link to the prototype, which correctly lists the methods like `getCenter` and `getContainer`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/y63u5utf/7/

Comment: Yep thanks, I feel a little silly for asking this question.  I'll leave it up in case it helps someone else.